# Why 80 % of my model is missing when exported from blender and imported into unreal engine 4?

Tags: export, import, unreal-engine

[image]

[image]

The first image is in blender and the second one is in unreal engine 4. I parented the top half of the gun and the barrel of the gun to the bottom part of the gun. The top half of the gun is parented to an armature. When i export from blender i select the whole gun and ticked selected objects in the export window and then export. In unreal engine, only the top half of the gun is visible while the bottom half disappears. Please help and ask if you need more screenshots to help solve the problem.

---

[image]

[image]

[image]

In picture 1 you can see the animation is broken up into several files even though i only have 1 animation linked to one bone and another one linked to another bone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the missing objects dont have a bone assosiated with them. Try assigning a bone to every object.

Comment: Thanks, that worked but now when i import the model into unreal engine, the animations associated with the model are split up into different fbx extensions and don't look anything like the animations in blender.

Answer (score 0):

I export from blender set to metric .1    and use the fbx... but I leave scale at 1.0 in the export menu... also in that menu (select mesh for a 3d model) (select armature and mesh for a skeletal mesh)... only select armature for a animation... but give it a different name.  always use face smoothing...  I have it down to an art form now... no prob with anything from blender to ue4...